# Django nested templates

Tags: django

In trying to keep with DRY, I'm setting up my Django project HTML files now. I have successfully extracted most repeated information to my base.html page. On most (but not all) of my pages, my content is displayed within a general 'panel' which is basically just a container set-up with styling, but it's got a few div-tags to it so it looks a bit ugly and I'm having to type out the exact same code out several times on each page.

My idea was to extract this to a 'panel.html' then call it whenever I need it, for example some pages might just have one 'panel' whereas my dashboard (it's an administrative site) will have maybe 15+. So it seemed a better idea and cleaner to not have to type out all this code each time I need to set up a 'panel'.

My ideal page would look something like..

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

    {% extends 'panel.html' %}
    {% block panel_content %}
        Panel content...
    {% endblock panel_content %}

    {% extends 'panel.html' %}
    {% block panel_content %}
        Second panel content
    {% endblock panel_content %}

{% endblock content %}
```

I know I can't use extends multiple times but I'm using it just as an example for what it is I'm trying to achieve.

I am going to potentially have hundreds of these identical 'panels' across my site but each containing different content and it would be so much cleaner if I could just have one stored somewhere in a HTML file and call it however many times I need.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `include`

```
{% include "panel.html" %}
```

I should mention that too many `include` statements create a performance issue.